# Basic calculator features

Tags: android, calculator

I created a android-calculator. There is basic features like add, multiply, divide, sub.
but it works for integer values. not for float values and big digit values.
is there any free source code for that?

Comment: Is it that hard to cast your integers to float/double/etc.?

Comment: Where is your Integer Code ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're programming for Android you're most likely using Java. As such it should be as easy as using `double` type values instead of `int`. However you've provided a rather small amount of info so we're making some assumptions here.

Answering your question directly, here's a link to an open source Android calculator app:
[Android Calculator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidcalculat/?source=directory)